# Contains Statement Like the Like statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a quick question: in my project I have a Like statement query that allows a person to search a word and it pulls the information from the Access db column. The only things is: with the Like statement, it only allows the person to search by the first letter or number.

Is there any way to search anything in the column like a Contain statement? So basically I need a Contain query statement similar to this **" Like + ? '%'** "

Comment: do you mean `like '%word%'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MS Access, you should use: `LIKE '*word*'`

Link: [Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/operador-like-HA001231490.aspx)

In ANSI SQL, it would be: `LIKE '%word%'`

Comment: +1 hadn't noticed the mention of Access buried in the question text.